# Mismatch in statistics shown in opening credit scene

Tags: plot-explanation, den-of-thieves

In the opening credits *Den of Thieves* shows the statistics about the bank robbery as seen in the below screenshot:

[image]

Now, if we go top down then

**2400 times a year = 46 times a week = ~6 times a day = every 4 hours = every 240 minutes**

if we go bottom up then

**every 48 minutes = 30 times a day = 210 times a week = ~10920 times a year**

None of them matches, then what do they indicate?

Comment: Still doesn't quite add up, but it works a bit better if you assume they're only open 8 hours a day, 5 days a week.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, it seems that Labour Code of that country do not allow even bank robbers to do their "job" longer than 8 hours a day 5 days a week.

Comment: It indicates that statistics aren't actual precise....these are obviously rounded numbers.

Comment: I just thought it's probably easier to rob a bank via the front door whilst it's open than by tunnelling in when it's closed. **Note: I haven't tested this theory empirically ;-)*

Comment: @Paulie_D I wouldn't know how to round from 48 to 240 or from 10920 to 2400. It's a very peculiar rounding.

Comment: @Tetsujin: If you tunnel in while it's closed, it's a burglary, not a robbery. A robbery requires that you threaten someone by force. You can't threaten someone if nobody is there.

Comment: @Mouvier: You can only rob someone if they're there. Closed banks are usually empty, so there's nobody to rob.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Didn't know that.

Comment: @JörgWMittag https://stickman.qntm.org/comics.php?n=367 (StickManStickMan comics, the Guys postpone robbing the bank because it's closed)

Comment: There is also [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/41066/36020) on the skeptics.SE about some fact-checking.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: There's always the security guards...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

2400 times a year, divided by 52 weeks a year:

- 2400 / 52 = **46.15 robberies a week**

46.15 times a week, divided by 5 days a work week:

- 46.15 / 5 = **9.23 robberies a day**

9.23 times a day, over an 8 hour work day:

- 9.23 / 8 = 1.15 robberies per hour, or, **1 robbery every 52 minutes**.

### So, we have:

- 2400 robberies a year
- **46.15 vs. 44** robberies per week
- **9.23 vs. 9** robberies per day (using 5-day work week)
- **52 vs. 48** minutes between robberies occurring (using 8-hour work days)

And then, working it backwards:
1 robbery every 48 minutes => 10 robberies a day => 50 robberies a week => 2600 robberies a year.

So,

- 1 robbery every 48 minutes
- **10 vs. 9** robberies a day
- **50 vs. 44** robberies a week
- **2600 vs. 2400** robberies a year

IMO, the figures work out fine and aren't too far off (~10% off at most). It does seem though that the statistic is only using the typical operating hours of a business in the US, that being - Monday thru Friday, 8a to 5p - which suggests that all reported robberies within this statistic took place during a bank's working hours (or, at least, to me it does).

That being said, as @Paulie_D has mentioned, the statistic may not be that accurate.

Comment: Assuming a 7.25 hour work day gets you 48 minutes...  Uh, do they close for lunch?  : )

Comment: banks are notorious for having shorter hours.

Comment: @zzzzBov Right.. also, at least one day of the week (usually Friday) they close a bit early. And then, they're also typically closed on any government recognized holiday - but!, are usually open Saturday mornings - so, it's actually kind of messy when you look at it closer..

Comment: If you use a 7.5 hr work day, you get 48.75 minutes, just drop the decimal (don't round up) to get 48 minutes. The 44/week though still seems like an actual error to me, though. Not only can't you get it from 2400, but using 44 to calc the next step only gives you 8.8 per day, which (even with a 7.5 hr day), is over 51 minutes each.

Comment: When all banks were local, some branches would close earlier than others, largely depending on their distance from the central office.  Some documents had to be transported back the central office in time for overnight processing.  Branches out at the edges of the suburbs might close as early as 3 p.m. while those closer to the central office would stay open until 5 p.m.

Comment: I'd presume banks are closed on Christmas and several other occasions, lowering the number of workdays in a year - that `5` is probably something more like 4-point-something.

Comment: The bank's operating hours aren't relevant to the statistic.  If a bank that's only open for one minute a year were robbed, could you say "there's a bank robbed every minute of the year"?

Comment: The main point of the answer could be stated more clearly up front:  People don't (usually) rob banks when the banks are closed.  The stats are computed around _working_ days and _working_ hours.

Answer (score 30):

To be honest...it **doesn't matter** because

## They are all wrong.

There haven't been 2400 bank robberies a year in LA since the 1990's

[**2014 Article**](http://www.latinpost.com/articles/9324/20140322/los-angeles-california-longer-bank-robbery-capital-world-fbi-surprised.htm)

> Since the 1960s, the city of Los Angeles has become known as the Bank Robbery Capital of the World, but according to Los Angeles Times, after a half a century, FBI agents are now wondering, "where did all the bandits go?"
>
> The FBI's L.A. office comprises seven counties: Los Angeles, San Bernardino, Riverside, Orange County, Santa Barbara, Ventura and San Luis Obispo. During the peak of L.A.'s bank-robbery era in 1992, as many as 28 banks were robbed in a single day, the Times reported.
>
> The early '90s was the worst time for the seven-county region's banks with 2,641 robberies were logged while only 212 bank robberies occurred in 2013. Additionally, in 1983, L.A. had more bank heists than the New York, San Francisco, Portland, Ore., and Sacramento regions combined. The 2013 incidents are equivalent to less than 10 percent of the early '90s robberies, according to the Times.

---

Indeed, the FBI's [**own statistics**](https://www.fbi.gov/file-repository/bank-crime-statistics-2016.pdf/view) for 2016 show **Calfornia as a whole** had a grand total of 462 "Bank Crimes" from a US total of ALL bank crimes of 4251

Comment: It's interesting to note that this follows the general trend for crime since 1990 - a sharp and continuous drop.

Comment: @Knetic These films should have an opening prologue that explains they happen in a world that never banned leaded fuel.

Comment: @Knetic Identity theft is much more profitable and much more low rist